# Does .org really makes your visitor trust you more than .com?

Tags: user-behavior, urls, organization, user-preferences

I'm currently launching a new storytelling community, which its goal isn't targeted as making profit. Should we use `.com` or `.org`?

Talking beside buying both, I prefer `.org` since we're a community and not targeting to make profit (although we still got profit from ads). But since `.com` is way more popular and people usually try `.com` first, it really struggles me for the decision.

What really makes me struggles is that I've heard people will more likely to visit your site ending with `.org` since they believe you're make stuffs free and trying to make world better instead of trying to get money from their pocket. But does it really work like this? Does this benefit really worth you to chose `.org` instead of `.com`? Last, will extension really make visitor more likely to enter?

Or it's just a post that's trying to convince you to use `.org`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think less about how the domain extension will influence those few people who will come across the concept completely fresh (presumably in some web search results, or as a link in a list on another website).

Given the nature and size of storytelling communities, these completely new visitors will be far fewer in number than those who hear about it otherwise  (word of mouth, social sharing, etc.), and come to it with at least some information on board.

Ultimately, **it depends on what you want to communicate** to that majority of users.

**.org communicates all the things you described in your first paragraph. It means not in the moneymaking business. .com means the opposite.**

Sounds like you should go with .org and don't spend too much more time thinking about it, though if you're going to run ads and you're really not for profit, then you should think about providing some explanation of why there are ads.

Comment: Your right, but actually organization doesn't mean **non-profit** organization, most organization will still make profit in order to keep running

Comment: Right, but if you're just putting that surplus back into the the running and improvement of the company, i.e. not specifically trying to make and keep it as 'profit', then it's not really profit. By that definition any company solvent enough to be able to grow couldn't be a non-profit.

Answer (score 0):

you could find out by

1. Setting up a goal in google analytics or
2. Doing A/B testing with some tool similar too optimizely.

Comment: You've not really answered the question here. You've just told someone a way of finding out an answer. That's a bit like someone asking "*What does Horticulture mean?*" and you answering "*You can find the answer in a Dictionary*".